# How to resolve classes dynamically 

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-4.0, mef

I have to generate bills for customers, but depending on where they live, the bills contain almost the same data, but they are formatted much differently.  I have thought of several ways to handle this, such as:

```
public void GenerateBill(User user)
{
if(user.Location == "blah blah")
{
  //Code specific to this location
}
else if (user.Location == "dah dah")
{
  //Code specific to this location
}
}
```

The above method seems like it can get really long especially when new users in different locations keep popping up.  I thought about doing something like:

```
public void GenerateBillForUserInBlah();

public void GenerateBilForUserInDah();
```

but the above also seems like it will get out of hand and become a maintenance nightmare.

My other idea was to use an interface such as `IGenerateBill` and then do something like:

```
class UserInBlah : IGenerateBill
{
//Implement IGenerateBill members

}
```

but in the above, I would have to create a class for each User.  I may still have to do the above, but I though if the `Managed Extension Framework` would be useful here.  Is there an alternative solution?  The main problem is I won't know the user's location until runtime, so I will have to call the correct method at runtime depending on the user's location.

Comment: How different is the formatting? Can you narrow the changes down to catagory's then mix and match according to your customer's location ?

Comment: The formatting is extremely different.  In addition to that, some bills depending on location contain more or less data.

Comment: Hmm.  To be honest unless you're purposely trying to learn a new technique or something, the first thing you have with the if statements (or alternatively a switch) seems like a pretty realistic and easy to implement solution.  I don't really think it would be that hard to maintain or add to.

Comment: I don't think it's nightmare much to maintain, you can avoid if else clause by using Dictionary, I would refer option 1

Comment: @CuongLe - I just mentioned 2 users, but what if you are dealing with 60 locations for example, you have to maintain an if or switch case for each location or in your case, you mentioned dictionary, how would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this approach:

```
public interface IGenerateBill {}
```

is a more elegant and extensible, than others. And yes, MEF can help you here.
MEF has a "part metadata" concept. If you're not familiar with it, you can read about it [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/20/mef-for-beginner-metadata-part-8.aspx).

Conceptually, MEF metadata allows you to write `IGenerateBill` implementations, containing, e.g., country code, or locale. Later, at run-time, you can retrieve a proper implementation such a way:

```
[BillGenerator("en-us")]
public class EnUsGenerateBill : IGenerateBill {}
[BillGenerator("ru-ru")]
public class RuRuGenerateBill : IGenerateBill {}
[BillGenerator("de-de")]
public class DeDeGenerateBill : IGenerateBill {}

container.GetExports<IGenerateBill, BillGeneratorMetadata>().Single(export => export.Metadata.Locale == "en-us");
```

Comment: I am new to MEF, can you explain what this code is doing as well as the LINQ part.  My locations would be more like State Counties.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I've posted link to blog post series, called "MEF for **beginner**". Have you read this entries?

Comment: I just opened the link.  Quickly if you would just answer one thing, why not just put the MetaData in the class, what benefit does it give you?

Comment: @Xaisoft: The first reason is MEF-specific. Putting metadata into MEF export definition allows you to enumerate *exports* without instantiating *parts*, which are defined by exports. In your case, this allows you to find appropriate bill generator without creation of all available bill generators. The second reason - this contradicts concept of metadata. Country code for particular generator will be the same during lifetime of your application. It will be the same for every instance of particular generator class. So, what it should be placed in a class (e.g. as a property) for?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property inside every class that returns your the location name

For eg:

```
        interface IGenerateBill
        {
            void GenerateBill();
            string SupportedCountry { get; }
        }

        class UserInUs : IGenerateBill
        {
        //Implement IGenerateBill members

            public void GenerateBill()
            {
                //generate bill
            }

            public string SupportedCountry
            {
                get { return "US"; }
            }
        }
        class UserInRussia : IGenerateBill
        {
        //Implement IGenerateBill members

            public void GenerateBill()
            {
                //generate bill
            }

            public string SupportedCountry
            {
                get { return "Russia"; }
            }
        }
```

Client side Code will be :

```
        string country = //Get from user in runtime
        var billGenerator = BillgeneratorFactory.ResolveAll().ToList().First
        (x => x.SupportedCountry == country);
        billGenerator.GenerateBill;
```

Comment: Can you explain this code, especially the Client side code?  What does ResolveAll<> do?

Comment: YOu need to create a factory that will resolve all the concrete implementations of IGenerateBill and return as IEnumerable. In short,BillgeneratorFactory.ResolveAll() should return UserInRussia and UserInUS

Comment: Where does ResolveAll come from, is it from an IOC container?